# Handling module import errors in react native android emulator

Tags: javascript, react-native, error-handling

[Development Error: 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIHBD.png)

This is an error is have seemingly been completely unable to solve on my own, it appears to have something to do with importing modules and dependencies. however, I have tried everything I could within that perceptive and it has become clear that I have asbolutetly no clue how to solve this seemingly simple problem.

let me know if you have experience solving this issue, it seems all the other postings on stacking and GitHub are mostly useless.

Comment: Have you already imported react-native-gesture-handler as the first import in your index.js (or whatever file loads first)?  See the final step in the iOS section [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/)

Comment: yes, I've tried all the different combinations including downgrading the React version to see if that would help. nothing changed each attempt.

Comment: figured it out, turns out Expo has a hard time pulling dependencies from globally installed modules. so I had to simply use NPM install within the directory. a little odd but thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, nice.  Always good to avoid global dependencies wherever possible.